# Visual studio 6.0 installation specified location is invalid

Tags: visual-studio

I want to install visual studio 6.0 enterprise edition. It gives error at "locate visual studio" and the error is "specified location is invalid ,choose another " It does not allow me to choose another location.
I am stuck here for many days. Tried with different software of visual studio 6.0 but same problem. I must install visual studio 6.0 for some personal reasons and not any other. kindly cooperate with me !

Comment: What OS are you using?  I had a lot of trouble installing VS6 on Win7 x64.  I found a post on here that helped me out, but I don't have the link offhand.

Comment: Running the VS6 installer on a modern operating system is likely to be troublesome, a bit dangerous as well.  You'll also have plenty of problems after installing, debugging isn't going to work well.  You also ought to have seen a strong compatibility warning from Windows.  But that's just guessing without you providing *any* details.  Only consider installing it in a VM that boots a version of Windows no later than XP.

Comment: This site demands 10 points for screeen shots . Me tried it at XP and windows 7 64 bit. But in Vain!

Comment: Me too..... Don't know why